# extract parts of SQL statment with regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, extract

I want extract parts of SQL string like this:

```
SELECT *,somecolumn, anothercolum FROM sometable INNER JOIN anotherTable WHERE somecolumn>1
```

in variables:

```
aVariable = "*,somecolumn, anothercolum";
anotherVariable = "sometable INNER JOIN anotherTable";
Vaiable = "somecolumn>1";
```

I've tried this (in JavaScript):

```
/SELECT\s(\*|[\w\,\_\d]+)\sFROM\s([\w\,\_]]+)(?:\s(.*))
```

But it fails with `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Is there always going to be a `WHERE` clause?

Comment: nope, can be WHERE, ORDER BY, GROUP BY, or simply not exist.

Comment: I thought of catch the last group (where, groupby,... etc..) and process with another regexp...

Comment: I would not even use a regular expression.  The complexity of an SQL statement (nested selects, etc..) doesn't lend well to simple regex parsing.  You'd probably be better off tokenizing/lexical analysis and that's a whole nother level of fun.

Comment: My suggestion is for you to figure out what sorts of queries it is you plan on running and then split the string based on various tokens. I'm pretty sure you can't just get a one line answer for this question.

Comment: `Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.` - Jamie Zawinski

Comment: My apologies to the OP for the unhelpful (albeit appropriate) comment I made. I agree with climbage that you would be hard-pressed to find a RE that is robust enough to handle all cases. But maybe that is fine for your needs...

Answer (score 0):

```
/SELECT\s(.*?)\sFROM\s((?!WHERE|ORDER BY|GROUP BY).*?)(?:WHERE\s|ORDER BY\s|GROUP BY\s|\Z)(.*)/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var reg =/^(\s*select\s+)(\w+(\s+as\s+\w+\s*)?||\[\s*\w+\s*\](\s+as\s+\w+\s*)?||\*\s*)(\s*\,\s*\w+(\s+as\s+\w+\s*)?||\s*\,\s*\[\s*\w+\s*\](\s+as\s+\w+\s*)?)*(\,\*)?(\s+from\s+)\w+\s*(\s+where\s+\[?\s*\w+\s*\]?\s*((\+||\-||\*||\/||\%||\^||(\>\=)||(\<\=)||\=||\>||\<)\s*\[?\s*\w+\s*\]?)?(\s+and\s+\[?\s*\w+\s*\]?\s*((\+||\-||\*||\/||\%||\^||(\>\=)||(\<\=)||\=||\>||\<)\s*\[?\s*\w+\s*\]?)?(\s+and\s+\[?\s*\w+\s*\]?\s+like\s+\'\%?\s*\w+\W*\w+\s*((\+||\-||\*||\/||\%||\^||(\>\=)||(\<\=)||\=||\>||\<)\s*\w+)?\%?\')?)*\s*)?(\s+order\s+by\s+(\w+\s*((\+||\-||\*||\/||\%||\^||(\>\=)||(\<\=)||\=||\>||\<)\s*\w+)?(\s+desc||\s+asc)*)(\,\w+((\+||\-||\*||\/||\%||\^||(\>\=)||(\<\=)||\=||\>||\<)\w+)?(\s+desc||\s+asc)*)*)?(\s+group\s+by\s+\w+(\,\w+)?(\s+having\s+\w+(\s*(\+||\-||\*||\/||\%||\^||(\>\=)||(\<\=)||\=||\>||\<)\s*\w+)?(\s*\,\s*\w+\s*((\+||\-||\*||\/||\%||\^||(\>\=)||(\<\=)||\=||\>||\<)\s*\w+)?)?)?)?\s*$/g;
```

Comment: You need `/gi` at the end if you want to be able to match `SELECT` with `select` (case-insensitive).

Comment: Just tried running this regex in javascript... it contains errors it wont run for me but its WAY out of my league to debug LOL